# Wifi disabled by hardware switch

Tags: networking, wireless

I have tried to unblock it using the `rfkill` command and when I use the `rfkill list` command it gives this:

```
~$ sudo rfkill list
[sudo] password for brandon_x_fox: 
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

I have tried on the keyboard doing an FN command along with the wifi button and that does not work either. My laptop is a Toshiba Satellite c55-b5200.

Comment: This sounds like a hardware problem, not an ubuntu problem.   Several people had luck doing a system restore (see http://forums.toshiba.com/t5/Other-Satellite-Laptop-Models/Resolved-Cannot-find-or-enable-wireless-switch-on-Satellite-L755/td-p/231788 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is

restart your computer, and go to your BIOS settings by pressing  <kbd>esc</kbd> or <kbd>delete</kbd> or another key depending on your motherboard model.

set the BIOS settings to default.

then reboot to Ubuntu and problem solved :D

Comment: I will try this

Comment: just tryed doing this and it did not work...

Comment: so probably you have a hardware issue

Answer (score 0):

One other thing to try.  Power down the laptop, remove the power cord and battery, then press and hold the power button for 30 seconds.  Then connect the battery and power cord and see if the hard block is gone

Source [Toshiba Support Forum Solution](http://forums.toshiba.com/t5/Other-Satellite-Laptop-Models/Resolved-Cannot-find-or-enable-wireless-switch-on-Satellite-L755/m-p/231968#M13346)