# Wifi disabled by hardware switch on hp pavilion G6 2231-tx

Tags: 14.04, wireless

I have a hp pavilion G6 2231-tx laptop running ubuntu 14.04 and windows dual boot.
The wifi on my laptop is not working in ubuntu.
It shows Wi-fi is disabled by hardware swith when I hover over the network icon in the top right corner of my desktop.

I have seen several posts like:

[How do I fix a "Wireless is disabled by hardware switch" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139036/how-do-i-fix-a-wireless-is-disabled-by-hardware-switch-error)

[Wifi disabled by hardware switch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/670356/wifi-disabled-by-hardware-switch)

and many more.

Things I have already tried:

1. Checked the bios.
2. Hardware switch on my keyboard(f12/fn+f12)
3. `rfkill unblock all`
4. Install wifi driver,[Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) (`lspci -nn -d 14e4:` returned no result though)
5. Checked `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` what's blacklisted.

but those were of no help. Pls suggest a solution.

**Edit**

`lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; rfkill list` returns

`07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter [103c:18ec]
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes`

**EDIT2**

Now I followed this:
[Ralink rt3290 wifi driver is not working in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455030/ralink-rt3290-wifi-driver-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Now the message that "Wirelss is disabled by hardware switch" is removed but now there is no wifi signal at all.
now `rfkill list` returns no result.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 done sir.

Comment: @Pilot6 added another edit too.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an Ubuntu issue. This is not any driver issue. This is caused by me (and possibly you).

While watching some video... I tried to increase volume with: `Fn + F10` key combination ... But I mistakenly pressed `Fn + F12` which was `Wifi button` with 'Radio' symbol on it, which disabled my wifi connection.

Running below command in Terminal, you can see the issue:

```
> rfkill list all
    
    0: Toshiba Bluetooth: Bluetooth           #or whatever it is
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
    1: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: yes    `<------ that's because I press Wifi button (above) `mistakenly`
```

**Solution**: Press again the `Fn + F12` (or, some other key where you have Radio symbol)

Now run again the same command:

```
> rfkill list all

    0: Toshiba Bluetooth: Bluetooth           #or whatever it is
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
    1: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no

    <------ no means solved.
```

Now, go to:

> (Windows button, if you have on the keyboard) > Settings > Wifi > move
> to On > select your Wiki connection to enter credentials

Done, your internet is back on.

Reference = [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/507631)

I hope this works ...